# Sailjs testing a model

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, sails.js

I am trying to write some tests for a model that I create in Sails.js. The model is shown below:

```
/**
 * Users
 *
 * @module      :: Model
 * @description :: A short summary of how this model works and what it represents.
 * @docs        :: http://sailsjs.org/#!documentation/models
 */

var User = {

  /**
   * Attributes list for the user
   * @type {Object}
   */
  attributes: {
    password:{
      type:  'string',
      alphanumeric: true,
      required: true,
      minLength: 6
    },
    firstName: {
      type: 'string',
      maxLength: 50,
      minLength: 5,
      required: true
    },
    lastName:{
      type:  'string',
      maxLength: 50,
      minLength: 5,
      required: true
    },
    email: {
      type: 'email',
      unique: true,
      required: true
    }
  },

  /**
   * Function that hashes a password
   * @param  {Object}   attrs - user attributes list
   * @param  {Function} next  [description]
   * @return {[type]}         [description]
   */

  beforeCreate: function( attrs, next ) {
    var bcrypt = require('bcrypt');
    bcrypt.genSalt( 10, function( err, salt ) {
      if ( err ) return next( err );
      bcrypt.hash( attrs.password, salt, function( err, hash ) {
        if ( err ) return next( err );

        attrs.password = hash;
        next();
      });
    });
  }

};

module.exports = User;
```

The tests I have written are shown below:

```
var assert = require('assert')
  , Sails = require('sails')
  , barrels = require('barrels')
  , fixtures;

// Global before hook
before(function (done) {
  // Lift Sails with test database
  Sails.lift({
    log: {
      level: 'error'
    },
    adapters: {
      default: 'mongo'
    }
  }, function(err, sails) {
    if (err)
      return done(err);
    // Load fixtures
    barrels.populate(function(err) {
      done(err, sails);
    });
    // Save original objects in `fixtures` variable
    fixtures = barrels.objects;
  });
});

// Global after hook
after(function (done) {
  console.log();
  sails.lower(done);
});

// User test
describe('Users', function(done) {
  it("should be able to create", function(done) {
    Users.create({firstName: "johnny", lastName: "BeGood", email: "johnnybegood@example.com", password: "validpassword123"}, function(err, user) {
      assert.notEqual(user, undefined);
      done();
    });
  });

  it("should be able to destroy", function(done) {
    Users.destroy({email: "johnnybegood@example.com"}, function(err) {
      assert.equal(true, true);
    });
  });
});
```

However, I can only ever get the first test to pass, the output that I receive is shown below:

[image]

I am quite new to writing tests in node/sails. Would anyone be able to point me towards what I am doing wrong in this instance. I am making use of the following gist
https://gist.github.com/joukokar/57b14e034e41893407f0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using asynchronous Mocha tests, you must call the callback (`done();`) at the end:

```
it("should be able to destroy", function(done) {
  Users.destroy({email: "johnnybegood@example.com"}, function(err) {
    assert.equal(true, true);

    done();
  });
});
```

Also, I would test `assert.ifError(err)` instead of `assert.equal(true, true)` (if the code doesn't go there you simply won't see the assertion, but it won't mean you actually tested the case).

Comment: Thanks for this, I shall try this. I put in true, true just to see if it did not give me a timeout :)